# Detect if files are overridden in the installation directory

Tags: installation, makefile, cmake, automake

I'm configuring a CMake project from source and build and install it with `make`, i.e.,

```
$ ls
./build/  ./source/
$ cd build/
$ cmake ../source/
[...]
$ make
[...]
$ make install
[...]
```

I noticed now that the project is badly configured in that it contains numerous files with the same name that get overridden in the installation directory, e.g, `/usr/local/include/mystring.h` gets written to more than once by `make install`.

Is there a systematic way to detect if files are overridden within the same project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can wrap `install()` calls into your own function, which would store all installed files in cache list variable and check for existing item before actually call `install()`.

You may also check `${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/install_manifest.txt` file - maybe it would contain duplicates in your case.

Comment: Checking the install manifest for duplicate lines with `sort install_manifest.txt | uniq --count --repeated` did the trick.